# 'Expecting statement' after echo

Tags: php, html

So PHPStorm gives me a 'expecting statement' error after the following line:

```
echo $values;
```

Here's the part in the code:

```
<?php
            if(!empty($_POST)){
                $values = implode(', ', array_intersect_key($_POST, $boxes));
                $txt = $_POST['Zoeken'];
                echo $values;
                ​
                ?>
                <br>
                <?php
                echo $txt;
            }
            ?>
```

and this is the complete code (form):

```
<div id="filterList">
        <?php $boxes = [
            'first_name' => ['label' => 'Voornaam', 'value' => 'a_Voornaam'],
            'last_name' => ['label' => 'Achternaam', 'value' => 'a_Achternaam'],
            'address' => ['label' => 'Adres', 'value' => 'a_Adres'],
            'city' => ['label' => 'Plaats', 'value' => 'a_Woonplaats'],
            'zipcode' => ['label' => 'Postcode', 'value' => 'a_Postcode'],
        ]; ?>
        <form name="filter"  style="float:left;" method="post">
            <table>
                <?php foreach ($boxes as $name => $box) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label><?php echo $box['label']; ?>:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="inh" value="<?php echo $box['value']; ?>"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Zoeken</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Zoeken" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label style="margin-top:5px;"></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="submitfilter" type="submit" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
            if(!empty($_POST)){
                $values = implode(', ', array_intersect_key($_POST, $boxes));
                $txt = $_POST['Zoeken'];
                echo $values;
                ​
                ?>
                <br>
                <?php
                echo $txt;
            }
            ?>
        </form>
</div>
```

What could be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I copy/paste the code there appears to be an invisible character in the supposedly empty line.

So just remove the blank line indicated by `<-- odd character here`

```
        <?php
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            $values = implode(', ', array_intersect_key($_POST, $boxes));
            $txt = $_POST['Zoeken'];
            echo $values;
             <-- odd invisible character here             
            ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            echo $txt;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks, i knew it would have to be something really small.

Comment: These kind of thing can drive you batty